# Generating AMP Pages for E-Commerce/Specific Pages

Tags: amp-html

This is a general question wondering that when you utilize the AMP stack especially in the industry of E-Commerce, you have the concept of an AMP product page. However, looking at all the examples online, the primary product data appears to be static and embedded in beforehand. Does this mean that the AMP pages were generated beforehand? If so, is this simply implemented by a script that creates AMP HTML pages for each product?

The example product page is here: [Product Page](https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/amp_for_e-commerce_getting_started/#product-pages)

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessary. AMP has pretty enough tools to make dynamic and interactive pages. For example, you can combine amp-list with amp-state and amp-selector and get interactive products [listing page](https://prestashop7.devoffice.com/meilleur/amp/index.php?fc=module&module=jxamp&id_product=1&controller=product&id_lang=2)

or [product info page](https://prestashop7.devoffice.com/meilleur/amp/index.php?fc=module&module=jxamp&id_product=1&controller=product&id_lang=2)

Read the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/) and do not afraid to experiment.

Comment: Do you know if there is a GitHub example of such workflow?

Comment: Follow this guideline and I think it would help you. There are some code examples in it https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/interactivity. Just keep in mind that all responses you need to get from your back-end must be a dynamic json array instead of that static one which the guideline provides

Comment: I guess my question is how does the product listing page transition to a product info page. Does each product info page have to be created beforehand? Let's say that you have two products, shirts and shoes, do you have to predefine amp html pages for each product (i.e. amp html for shirt and then one for shoes)

Comment: I suppose you would query the backend using `amp-state` and say an ID and return data such as image resource and other data. Is this correct?

Comment: Each of your pages should be generated the same way as your regular pages do but with different(AMP) markup. So they are creating automatically within an e-Commerce system leverages. In the example, it is Prestashop e-Commerce which generates pages within a module.

Comment: Ahh okay, so we do have to generate the pages using a script or program.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You send requests to your back-end and get all information within responses and then handle it in your front-end within AMP tools

Comment: So you can create a product l list page and a product info page and dynamically generate and populate product data on the product info amp page.

Comment: It should work the same way as your CMS works and just generate other instances of regular pages with different markup